# Automatic Property Upgrading

Tags: c#

I am creating an application just for practicing c# as well as new programming ways. So i came across the idea that i create an application that stores information about "soldiers" ex. Names, ranks, titles, etc... but the trick here is that i want the soldier title to be automatically upgraded when it's rank increases.

#### I have created a small application to demonstrate the idea.

### Soldier Class

```
public class Soldier
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Rank { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public Soldier(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        RefreshTitle();
    }

    public void Rankup(int rank = -1)
    {
        if (-1 != rank)
            Rank = rank;
        else
            Rank++;

        RefreshTitle();
    }

    public void RefreshTitle()
    {
        Title = SoldierRankLibrary.GetSoldierTitle(Rank);
    }
}
```

### Soldier Rank Library

```
public class SoldierRankLibrary
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> RankDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
                                                          {
                                                              {0, "Novice"},
                                                              {1, "Second Lieutenant"},
                                                              {2, "First Lieutenant"},
                                                              {3, "Captain"},
                                                              {4, "Major"},
                                                              {5, "Lieutenant Colonel"},
                                                              {6, "Colonel"}
                                                              //etc...
                                                          };

    public static string GetSoldierTitle(int requiredRank)
    {
        return RankDictionary.FirstOrDefault(rank => rank.Key == requiredRank).Value;
    }
}
```

### Using the code

```
static void Main()
{
    //Create new soldier...
    var soldier = new Soldier("Daniel");

    //Print soldier info...
    PrintSoldierInfo(soldier);

    //Upgrade soldier...
    soldier.Rankup();

    //Print soldier info...
    PrintSoldierInfo(soldier);

    Console.Read();
}

static void PrintSoldierInfo(Soldier soldier)
{
    Console.WriteLine("****************************************");
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", soldier.Name);
    Console.Write("Rank: ");
    switch (soldier.Rank)
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("novice");
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("**");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("***");
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("****");
            break;
        case 5:
            Console.WriteLine("*****");
            break;
        case 6:
            Console.WriteLine("******");
            break;
        case 7:
            Console.WriteLine("*******");
            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", soldier.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("****************************************");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

### Conclusion

***I am really waiting for your answers and i hope you give me detailed information about what i miss, what i can do better, how could i improve this code.***

Comment: Based upon the code provided, you are avoiding the benefits of polymorphism by using enums and switches and string literals.  According to Fowler (and his disciples) these can be classified as 'code smells'.  Consider polymorphism and OO design.

Comment: While technically not relevant, *novice* is not a military rank :-) Pick your country from the list: [Wikipedia: List of comparative military ranks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_comparative_military_ranks)

Comment: @Lstor : hehehe i know i was just creating a question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Get rid of SoldierRankLibrary**

- `GetSoldierRank()` belongs in the `Soldier` class. That's what `Rank { get; set; }` is for.
- the `Dictionary` will be replaced by an `enum` (see below). An `enum` does not need be inside of any class. You can use boolean operators on enums ("<", "==", ...)

**Use Enum instead of Dictionary**

- Your dictionary is mimicking an Enum. In other words and Enum
  inherently associates a number with a name. And in general using Enum
  is preferred over strings.
- Make separate `OfficerRank` and `EnlistedRank` enums if that works
  better.
- I like @Nik's answer with "unknown". But I'd make it "0" instead of
  "-1". The natural default value of an enum variable is zero.
- If the underlying int values matter elsewhere in code just make sure you put the ranks in the desired order.

**Soldier Class**

- `Rank` and `Title` appear to be the same thing. Do you really need to refer to the soldier's rank by its underlying (integer) value?
- Explicitly set variables in the constructor. We all know default values for .NET types, but you want to convey intent and meaning.
- Exhaustively set the entire state in the constructor. Again, intent and meaning.
- `Rankup()` - change name to `Promote()`. Don't pass in an integer, pass in something that has meaning. We're going to utilize `Rank` enum so this fills the bill.
- `RefreshTitle()` - obsolete. Rank/Title is the same thing. The `Rank` enum keeps us from having to deal with a string and an int.
- Property mis-use. It makes no sense to have a `private Title set` and
  a `public RefreshTitle()`. Think of a `Property` as a method. A lot of existing code goes away simply by using the public get properties.
- Override `ToString()`. Now `PrintSoldierInfo()` disappears.

**New Code**

```
public enum Rank {undefined, BuckPrivate, Sergeant, Lieutenant, Captain}

public class Soldier {
    public string   Name { get; protected set; }
    public Rank     Rank { get; protected set; }

    public Soldier (string name) {
        Name = name ?? "No Name";       // null coalescing.
        Rank = Rank.undefined;   // maybe private if enlisted or lieutenant if officer 
    }

    public void Promote (Rank newRank) {
        if ((int)this.Rank < (int)newRank ) this.Rank = newRank;
        // we don't allow Demotion in this method. 
    }

   public override string ToString() {
       Stringbuilder me = new Stringbuilder();  // need to import System.Text to use Stringbuilder

// C# string formatting avoids clumsy string concatination; clearer and less error prone
       me.AppendLine("Name: {0}  Rank: {1}", Name,Rank); 

       return me.ToString();  // Stringbuilder must be converted to a string.
   }
}
```

**Using Soldier**

```
Soldier grunt = new Soldier("Sad Sack");
grunt.Promote(Rank.Sergeant);
Console.WriteLine (grunt); // ToString() is automagically called.
```

Comment: This is very nice... There are some errors though so i edited your answer please accept the edit

Comment: 1. `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of an `enum` can make sense if the `string`s should be human readable, you can't have `"Second Lieutenant"` in an `enum`. 2. You can't use `private` as an `enum` value like that, because it's a keyword. You should use the normal .Net naming conventions and write `Private`. Or you could use `@private`.

Comment: The issues that `enum` solves and/or prevents here trumps the need to extract proper grammar from `enum` values. Proper grammar is a secondary issue. Then indeed a `Dictionary<Rank, string>` (vice `Dictionary<int, string>`) would do well for extracting `Second Lieutenant` (2 words) from `Rank.SecondLieutenant`. But for Heaven's sake get away from obtuse use of integers and express things in terms of the problem domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `Rank` type to some `enum`.

```
public enum Rank
{
    Unknown = -1,
    Novice = 0,
    SecondLieutenant = 1,
    ....
}

public static class SoldierRankLibrary
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> RankDictionary = new Dictionary<Rank, string>
                                                      {
                                                          {Rank.Novice, "Novice"},
                                                          ....
                                                      };

     public static string DisplayName(this Rank rank)
     {
         if (RankDictionary.ContainsKey(rank))
         {
             return RankDictionary[rank];
         }
         return rank.ToString();
     }
}

public class Soldier
{
     public string Name { get; private set; }
     public Rank Rank { get; private set; }
     public string Title { get { return Rank.DisplayName(); } }

     public Soldier(string name, Rank rank = Rank.Unknown)
     {
         Name = name;
         Rank = rank;
     }

     public void Rankup()
     {
         Rank++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Very nice well detailed explanation thank you very much Nik